# В Функциях высшего порядка, какая функция выполнится первой, та, которая передана как аргумент, или та, в которую передали функцию?

Tags: javascript, функции

```
Function f1(f2) {}
Function f2() {}
```

`F1(f2)` --- какая функция выполнится первее f1, или f2?

Comment: никакая, т.к. f1  тут не вызывается, а f2 - не известно вызывается или нет

Comment: Если абстрагироваться от того, что вы написали, и каждая последующая функция будет ждать выполнения переданной функции в качестве аргумента, первой будет выполнена та, которая передана аргументом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, на самом деле тут вообще синтаксические ошибки кругом.

Answer (score 1):

Строго говоря, никакая функция не выполнится, начнём с того что в JS функции декларируются через ключевое слово `function`, а не класс `Function` (Хотя такое и возможно, но именно в вашем случае это сделано некорректно) и в коде после декларации функции она нигде не вызывается.

Теперь говоря о вопросе, всё становится неоднозначно, так как `f1`, условно говоря будет вызываться первым, мы это легко может проверить используя `Proxy`:

```js
function f1(f2) {
  f2()
}

function f2() {}

let call_f1 = new Proxy(f1, {
  apply(target, thisArg, args) {
    console.log('Calling', target)

    return target.apply(thisArg, args)
  }
})

let call_f2 = new Proxy(f2, {
  apply(target, thisArg, args) {
    console.log('Calling', target)

    return target.apply(thisArg, args)
  }
})

call_f1(call_f2)
```

Как мы видим в первую очередь вызывается `f1`, но вот если говорить о функционале, то вот он, может находиться как до момента вызова `f2`, так и после, если у вас появился вопрос, а какая разница? То вот вам ответ, большая, это можно увидеть на этих двух примерах:

```js
function f1(f2) {
  let btn = document.createElement('button')
  btn.id = 'btn'
  btn.textContent = 'Button'
  document.body.appendChild(btn)

  f2()
}

function f2() {
  document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = () => console.log('hello!')
}

f1(f2)
```

И тут же тот же код, только функция `f2` выполняется в начале:

```js
function f1(f2) {
  f2()

  let btn = document.createElement('button')
  btn.id = 'btn'
  btn.textContent = 'Button'
  document.body.appendChild(btn)
}

function f2() {
  document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = () => console.log('hello!')
}

f1(f2)
```

Тут чётко видно, что вылезает ошибка, т.к. кнопка ещё не успела появиться, отходя от этого примера следует, что `f2` **не** стоит вызывать раньше чем успела сработать функция `f1` (её функционал), если конечно `f2` обрабатывает данные которые имеют отношение к функции `f1`.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда `f1` выполнится первой, а `f2` даже не будет вызвана. Иногда `f2` выполнится первой - завершится до завершения `f1`:

```js
const f1 = (g, c) => {
    if (c) {
        g();
    }
    console.log('f1');
};

const f2 = () => console.log('f2');

console.log('----------');
f1(f2, false);
console.log('----------');
f1(f2, true);
console.log('----------');
```